# How to model when I can respond to an event, based on last response

Tags: r, if-statement, events, conditional-statements

I want to model whether I can respond to an event. This depends on when I last responded to an event. I need to take these conditions into account:

- Events can occur throughout the day, but I can only respond between 7 am and 11pm.
- Time between events can vary, but time between responses must be at least 90 min.
  In other words, you can only respond to a new event if your last response was at least 90 min ago.
  It is important, that I don’t want a 1 if the time between events is >90 but I only want a 1 if the time between an event and last response is >90.

```
structure(list(event_day = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), event_hr = c(1, 
8, 9, 9, 10, 12), event_minute = c(41L, 25L, 22L, 41L, 26L, 1L
), onset_time = c(101, 505, 562, 581, 626, 721)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Onset_time is the time since start of the model in minutes. We would like to have a “respond_col” with 1 when we can respond and 0 when we cannot respond. For these 6 rows, the respond_col is supposed to result in 0,1,0,0,1,1.
This sums up what I want to do but I don’t know how to code this:
If difference in onset_time>90 since last 1 in respond_col, print 1 in respond_col, else print 0 in respond_col.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table like you have here). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @ShawnHemelstrand. I have replaced the table for a dataset using dput!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a few data modifications and a `for` statement.

This requires 2 libraries, `hms` and `tidyverse`.

I added rows to your data frame to test some of the conditions you mentioned.

```
library(hms)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read.table(header = T, text = "
                    event_day event_hr event_minute onset_time
1         0        1           41        101
2         0        8           25        505
3         0        9           22        562
4         0        9           41        581
5         0       10           26        626
6         0       12            1        721")

# add rows for testing
dat <- do.call("rbind", 
               list(dat, c(0, 12, 59, 721 + 58), 
                    c(0, 14, 20, 721 + 58 + 21 + 60),
                    c(0, 23, 5, 860 + 45 + 8 * 60),
                    c(1, 7, 5, 860 + 45 + 16 * 60))) %>% as.data.frame()
#   event_day event_hr event_minute onset_time
# 1         0        1           41        101
# 2         0        8           25        505
# 3         0        9           22        562
# 4         0        9           41        581
# 5         0       10           26        626
# 6         0       12            1        721
# 7         0       12           59        779
# 8         0       14           20        860
# 9         0       23            0       1380
# 10        1        7            5       1865
```

The next step requires a vector that stores the time thresholds (7-11) and the following changes to `dat`: a column with the time differences, a field that indicates whether or not the time meets the 7 am - 11 pm criteria, and 2 columns filled with 0: accumulated time and response. Both of these columns are filled in the `for` statement. The function `hms` is from the library `hms`.

```
these <- c(hms(0, 0, 7), hms(0, 0, 23)) # day constraints

(dat1 <- dat %>% mutate(
  time = c(0, diff(onset_time)), # 0 for first row, then the rest
  time_avail = between(hms(hours = event_hr, minutes = event_minute), 
                       these[1], these[2]),
  # accumulated time since last reset; whether response is warranted (conditions met)
  accum_time = 0, response = 0))
#    event_day event_hr event_minute onset_time time time_avail accum_time response
# 1          0        1           41        101    0      FALSE          0        0
# 2          0        8           25        505  404       TRUE          0        0
# 3          0        9           22        562   57       TRUE          0        0
# 4          0        9           41        581   19       TRUE          0        0
# 5          0       10           26        626   45       TRUE          0        0
# 6          0       12            1        721   95       TRUE          0        0
# 7          0       12           59        779   58       TRUE          0        0
# 8          0       14           20        860   81       TRUE          0        0
# 9          0       23            5       1385  525      FALSE          0        0
# 10         1        7            5       1865  480       TRUE          0        0
```

For the `for` statement, I'm using a boolean flag: `reset` for when the cumulative time resets.

```
reset = F # boolean flag for cumulative time
for(j in 1:nrow(dat1)) {
  if(j == 1 | reset) {        # first row or reset
    dat1$accum_time[j] <- dat1$time[j]
    reset = F
  } else {                    # any row other than first or reset
    dat1$accum_time[j] <- dat1$accum_time[j - 1] + dat1$time[j]
  }                           # determine whether trigger the reset
  if(dat1$accum_time[j] > 90 & dat1$time_avail[j]) {
    dat1$response[j] <- 1
    reset = T
  }
}
dat1
#    event_day event_hr event_minute onset_time time time_avail accum_time response
# 1          0        1           41        101    0      FALSE          0        0
# 2          0        8           25        505  404       TRUE        404        1
# 3          0        9           22        562   57       TRUE         57        0
# 4          0        9           41        581   19       TRUE         76        0
# 5          0       10           26        626   45       TRUE        121        1
# 6          0       12            1        721   95       TRUE         95        1
# 7          0       12           59        779   58       TRUE         58        0
# 8          0       14           20        860   81       TRUE        139        1
# 9          0       23            5       1385  525      FALSE        525        0
# 10         1        7            5       1865  480       TRUE       1005        1
```

Let me know if you have any questions.